# Logic Programming: Transforming B:-A C:-A to B,C:-A

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, terminology, logic-programming

I hope I've come to the right place... it's (probably) a fairly straightforward Logic Programming question.

If I have two clauses of the form:
`B:-A C:-A`
I can transform these into:
`B,C:-A`

(**Edit:** *where `B,C` is a conjunction. I'm doing bottom-up evaluation and it's useful to me to represent multiple clauses with the same body using one clause with a conjunction of the respective heads. This seems trivial, but I'm wondering if there's a name for such a transformation—however, I know that the resulting clause is no longer a Horn clause.*)

Does anyone know if this transformation has a name, and if so, can anyone provide a pointer (preferably online) to somewhere that describes it.

Many thanks (from a n00b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this is an instance of the fact that $(A \supset B) \wedge (A \supset C)$ is equivalent to $A \supset (B \wedge C)$. A different type isomorphism, namely that $(B \supset A) \wedge (C \supset A)$ is equivalent to $(B \vee C) \supset A$, looks more like what you wrote down, but that's because in logic programming notation we write B :- A when we mean $A \supset B$. (Note: $\supset$ is "implies," $\wedge$ is "and," and $\vee$ is "or.")

What you're trying to do is related to the *binarization* transformation, which is discussed in McAllester's "On the complexity analysis of static analyses." There may be a better name for the transformation, but if so, it wasn't known the authors of the paper "[A succinct solver for ALFP](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.15.2025)" (***A***lternating ***L***east ***F***ixed***p***oint formulas are a generalization of Horn clauses for bottom-up logic programs such as yours) - in Example 1 on page 4 they discuss a similar transformation and just call it "exploiting the possibility of sharing of pre-conditions."

Comment: Man, I have got to stop shallow parsing whole fields of research, and getting my education from Wikipedia. Maybe then I can find out what the wheel is called *before* I reinvent it. (But first I need to finish my PhD o.O)

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer. I shouldn't post late in the evening.

Comment: I understand the feeling (applies to both comments!)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of [CCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), your transformation is interpreted as “$mb:A\to B, mc:A\to C$ is transformed to $\langle mb, mc \rangle : A\to B\times C$”, i.e. the [product of morphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)).